# Javascript--tab key not working

Tags: javascript, textbox, onkeyup

I have a javascript program that, in part, poses a division problem and asks for the quotient and remainder to be inserted in two different textboxes.  The program in this instance looks like this:

!(C:\Users\Owen Walker\Dropbox (Personal)\Sebzo javascript\quotient_remainder.JPG)
For some reason--the program is fairly complicated--when both textboxes are visible, the user cannot Tab and Shift+Tab from one textbox to the other.

I have therefore written two functions: handleTabInQuotientTextbox() and handleShiftTabInRemainderTextbox(), that, when called in onkeyup from the quotient and remainder textboxes, set the focus on the other textbox. In other words, they do the right thing when Tab is pressed in the quotient textbox, i.e., the caret goes to the reminder textbox, and vice versa when the Shift+Tab keys are pressed in the remainder textbox.  What's wrong is that one can no longer enter numbers or other text into the two textboxes.

Here is the code for the two functions:

```
function handleTabInQuotientTextbox(evt) {
var e = event || evt; // for trans-browser compatibility
var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;

if (charCode == 9 && tentative_game_chosen == 'rd') {

document.getElementById("user_input_for_remainder_div").focus();
}

return false;
}



function handleShiftTabInRemainderTextbox(evt) {
var e = event || evt; // for trans-browser compatibility
if(e.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 9 && tentative_game_chosen == 'rd') { 

    document.getElementById("user_input_div").focus();
}
return false;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your image failed to upload. Have you looked into tabindex?

Comment: You should totally use tabindex.

Comment: Thank you both. tabIndex worked perfectly.